# GridSearchCV gives different result

Tags: python-3.x, ensemble-learning, gridsearchcv

I have applied a `gridsearchCV` with estimators of `DecisionTreeClassifier`, `RandomForestClassifier`, `LogisticRegression`, `XGBClassifier` used all of them in ensemble learning.

The result that `gridSearchCV` will give with all these estimators are different in my system and my friend's system with same data of testing and training, I don't know why?

We are using same data for training and testing but `gridsearch` is giving different result for these data in both the system, just want to know what should be changed to make the system to give same result on any system?

```
gs_dt = GridSearchCV(estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42,class_weight={1:10, 0:1}),
                  param_grid=[{'max_depth': [ 2,  4,  6, 8, 10], 
                               'criterion':['gini','entropy'], 
                               "max_features":["auto", None], 
                               "max_leaf_nodes":[10,20,30,40]}],
                  scoring=scoring,
                  cv=10,
                  refit='recall')

gs_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, oob_score = True,class_weight={1: 10/11, 0: 1/11}),
                    param_grid=[{'max_depth': [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 20, None],
                                 'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
                                 'min_samples_leaf': [2, 4, 8], 
                                 'min_samples_split': [10, 20]}],
                    scoring=scoring,
                    cv=10,
                    n_jobs=4,
                    refit='recall')

gs_lr = GridSearchCV(estimator=LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr',random_state=42,class_weight={1:10, 0:1}),
              param_grid=[{'C': [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1 ,1],
                          'penalty':['l1','l2']}],
              scoring=scoring,
              cv=10,
              refit='recall')

gs_gb = GridSearchCV(estimator=XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1),
                    param_grid=[{'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2],
                                 'max_depth': [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 20],
                                 'min_samples_leaf': [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], 
                                 'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt']}],
                    scoring=scoring,
                    cv=10,
                    n_jobs=4,
                    refit='recall')
```

For example first `gridsearchcv` gives this result on my system:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight={1: 10, 0: 1}, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=8, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=42,
            splitter='best')
```

And on my friend's system it gives:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight={0: 1, 1: 10}, criterion='gini',
                       max_depth=10, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False,
                       random_state=42, splitter='best')
```

Similarly I got different result on my and my friend's system.

Comment: Please show the relevant code like where have you applied `gridsearchCV`

Comment: i have changed it

Comment: I think it's because you are using `random_state`. Try putting `random _state = None`.

Comment: i have done that also but did not get same result in both the system. even when we are using the same value for `random state` we didn't get the same result

Comment: you changed that in in all i mean decisiontreeclassifier and all ?

Comment: yes i have changed in all the classifiers but it didn't help me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197139/discussion-between-rex5-and-shubham).